# Return even and odd numbers between dynamic ranges in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a code(function) that takes in two parameters a and b, and returns all the even number between a and b if a is greater than b else it should return the odd numbers between a and b.

this is my code.

```
function number_ranges (a, b) {

    let numbers = [];

    if (a > b){
        for (let i = b; i < a; i++){
            if (i > b){
                numbers.push(i);
            }
        }
    }else{
        for (let i = a; i < b; i++){
            if (i > a){
                numbers.push(i);
            }
        }
    }

    const result = numbers.filter(function(num){
        return a > b ? num % 2 === 0: num % 2 === 1;
    });
    return result;
}
```

I would like to see a different approach because i cant seem to be able to pass all the test cases

Comment: does the order matter?

Comment: Why are you pushing all of the number in and than filtering? There is no need....

Comment: Do you have an example of a test case where it's not working?

Comment: `if(i > a)` so why not just start it at `i=a+1` and not have to do that check?

Comment: no the order doesnt matter but naturally it would be sorted since i would  start iterating from the lowest.....correct me if i am wrong though i am a newbie

Comment: Odd and even are pretty easy to determine. Just MOD 2 the number. `x%2` --- `0` is even, `1` is odd.

Comment: the test case for javascript is hidden but this is the similar python version  test.assert_equals(number_game(2,12), [3, 5, 7, 9, 11])
test.assert_equals(number_game(0,0), [])
test.assert_equals(number_game(2,12), [3, 5, 7, 9, 11])
test.assert_equals(number_game(200,180), [180, 182, 184, 186, 188, 190, 192, 194, 196, 198])
test.assert_equals(number_game(180,200), [181, 183, 185, 187, 189, 191, 193, 195, 197, 199])

Answer (score 1):

I used this function `f=(a,b)=>[...ArrayMath.max(a,b))].map((q,i)=>i).filter(z=>(a<b?!(z%2):z%2)&&z>=Math.min(a,b))`

I first create a range from 1 to `b` as follow `[...Array(Math.max(a,b))].map((q,i)=>i)`

Then I filter with `a<b?!(z%2):z%2`. If a greater than b then a keep the even numbers, else the odds.

Also I keep only those number greater or equal to the first parameter using `&&z>=Math.min(a,b)`

```js
f=(a,b)=>[...Array(Math.max(a,b))].map((q,i)=>i).filter(z=>(a<b?!(z%2):z%2)&&z>=Math.min(a,b))
console.log(f(10, 5))
console.log(f(5, 10))
```

Comment: Your function returns evens when a < b, in the opposite case it returns an empty array, please check the code.

Comment: @Joe25 Thanks for noticing, I got it inverted (not too good at english :c).

Comment: yeah it works pretty nice except that it returns the last number for the even number filter ....it's supposed to return only numbers in between ignoring the start and end point

Answer (score 1):

You could take a sningle loop and a check if the value is even or or in combination with a check for the order.

```js
function getEvenOdd(a, b) {
    var inc = +(a < b) || -1,
        i,
        result = [];
     for (i = a; i !== b + inc; i += inc) {
         if (+(inc === 1) !== i % 2) {
             result.push(i);
         }
     }
     return result;
}

// even
console.log(getEvenOdd(3, 10).join(' ')); // [4, 6, 8, 10]
console.log(getEvenOdd(4, 10).join(' ')); // [4, 6, 8, 10]
console.log(getEvenOdd(3, 9).join(' '));  // [4, 6, 8]
console.log(getEvenOdd(4, 9).join(' '));  // [4, 6, 8]

// odd
console.log(getEvenOdd(10, 3).join(' ')); // [9, 7, 5, 3]
console.log(getEvenOdd(10, 4).join(' ')); // [9, 7, 5]
console.log(getEvenOdd(9, 3).join(' '));  // [9, 7, 5, 3]
console.log(getEvenOdd(9, 4).join(' '));  // [9, 7, 5]
```